# How to get lots of tweets using ruby twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

I wrote some ruby to return all the tweets containing a phrase within a time range.  However this code will return at most 1,500 tweets.  How can I get more than 1,500 tweets? (I'm hoping to get hundreds of thousands of tweets)

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"

    # returns a list of tweets containing the phrase within the dates specified
    # returns either @max_tweets tweets or all tweets found
    # @param phrase - a phrase to search for
    # @param from_date - begining date of the search ex."2011-02-28"
    # @param until_date - ending date of the search ex. "2011-03-01"
    def get_tweets(phrase, from_date, until_date)

      search = Twitter::Search.new.containing(phrase).since_date(from_date).until_date(until_date)

      #get all the tweets
      tweets = search.fetch
      next_tweets = search.fetch_next_page
      while(tweets.size < @max_tweets && next_tweets != nil) 
        tweets = tweets + next_tweets
        next_tweets = search.fetch_next_page
      end

      return tweets.first(@max_tweets)
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Twitter API docs](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) state

```
rpp
The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100

page
The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page).
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=10
```

So it appears that 1500 is a built-in limit.

Comment: Okay if the ruby twitter gem won't work, do you have any other ideas to get a lot of tweets?

Comment: Twitter has a streaming API that lets you collect and filter tweets in real time; I'm pretty sure that's how the companies that "harvest" tweets get them. http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api